# open h5 file on colab and find packages in libraries

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have a problem with a h5 file. I don't know how to open it. It is in my google drive.

This is the code:

```
import h5py
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy 
import mathplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy import get_window    forma onda
import io
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
url="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSEbrMYNxiDLwfWHwKGvqbwoP5Hygy2f/view?usp=sharing"
with open(url, 'r') as f:

    UTC_TIME=f["UTC_TIME"][()][:,0] 
    GEO_LAT=f["GEO_LAT"][()][:,0]
    GEO_LON=f["GEO_LON"][()][:,0]
    ALT=f["ALTITUDE"][()][:,0]
    Workmode=f["WORKMODE"][()][:,0]  
   
    A131_W=f["A131_W"][()][:,0]  
    A132_W=f["A132_W"][()][:,0]  
    A133_W=f["A133_W"][()][:,0]  
    A131_P=f["A131_P"][()][:,0]
    A132_P=f["A132_P"][()][:,0]
```

This is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4514d49cf415> in <module>()
     22 
     23 #OrbitNumber=url.split("_")[6];
---> 24 with open(url, 'r') as f:
     25     #f.write(r.content)
     26 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSEbrMYNxiDLwfWHwKGvqbwoP5Hygy2f/view?usp=sharing'
```

An other problem is that colab could not find the packages into the libraries (ex: get_window in scipy) although they are installed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Something is wrong with the file name or url.  It can't find it on your system.

Comment: Look at using the `requests` library to get data via the `https` protocol.